# I'm trying to make a progrm that saves an object to a file and then reads the object from the file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, file, save

I think it saves the object because it makes the .txt file but when I run the program, after I input the inputs it outputs "Error initializing stream". I am new to Java and coding in general so I was just wondering what I am doing wrong.

Here i what I get when I run the code:

"What type of costume do you want?

*gorilla suit*

What type of mask do you want?

*gorilla*"

This is your outfit.

Costume: gorilla suit

Mask:    gorilla

Error initializing stream"

I would expect the contents of the object ("gorilla suit" and "gorilla") to 
output on the last line, but instead it outputs "Error initializing stream".

Here is the runner class:

```
class RunHalloween2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);


      Halloween outfit = new Halloween();

      System.out.println("What type of costume do you want?");
      outfit.setCostume(Input.nextLine());

      System.out.println("What type of mask do you want?");
      outfit.setMask(Input.nextLine());

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("This is your outfit.");
      System.out.println("Costume: " + outfit.getCostume());
      System.out.println("Mask:    " + outfit.getMask());


        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("myOutfit.txt"));
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

            // Write objects to file
            o.writeObject(outfit);

            o.close();
            f.close();

            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("myOutfit.txt"));
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

            // Read objects

            outfit = (Halloween) oi.readObject();


            System.out.println(outfit.toString());

            oi.close();
            fi.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Posting your code is a good start but what exactly is the matter? What issues do you encounter? What have you done to try and resolve them? What is the expected result and what do you get instead? Can you post the error trace? The more information you provide, the higher the chance you'll get a helpful and timely reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per me There can be 2 mistake :-

1 - Your file name is `myOutfit.txt` but it should be `myOutfit.ser` .

2 - Your Halloween class does not implements serilization.

```
public class Halloween implements java.io.Serializable
```